# Why was Saudi Arabia removed from the UN's blacklist of child rights violators?

Tags: international-law, united-nations, human-rights, saudi-arabia

What is the UN's reasoning (or excuse) behind removing Saudi Arabia from a blacklist of child rights violators despite being blamed for the killing of hundreds of Yemeni children?

What is the official  website of this list?

Comment: This was the document you're looking for, before the recent edit: http://www.un.org/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=s/2016/360&referer=/english/&Lang=E .

Comment: I'm tempted to guess it had something to do with KSA [being on Human Rights Council](http://www.unwatch.org/again-saudis-elected-chair-of-un-human-rights-council-panel/) of the UN. (I'll omit the snarky yet true "because UN is a joke" response)

Comment: They threatened the UN to withdraw their financial support for UN projects.

Comment: @user4012, I'll add the snarky yet false "and if you're on the Human Rights Council you obviously don't violate child rights".

Comment: It's weird to put them on a list of child rights violators for mistreating foreign citizens abroad. I'd expect that only domestic policies should earn you that title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An effortless search would have been enough to get the answer.

The summery is, Saudi Arabia and its allies (mainly Gulf countries) put massive pressure on [Ban Ki Mun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ban_Ki-moon)'s office by threatening to cut aids for UN's humanitarian relief projects.

1. [UN ‘blackmailed’ into removing Saudi Arabia from blacklist after just a week](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/middle-east/un-saudi-arabia-blackmail-blacklist-removed-after-one-week-a7073046.html)

> UN sources said Ban Ki-moon’s office was barraged with calls from Gulf
>   Arab foreign ministers and ministers from the Organisation of Islamic
>   Cooperation (OIC) following the blacklisting.
>
> ...
>
> Ms Dujarric said Jordan, United Arab Emirates and Bangladesh had
>   complained to Mr Ban’s office, while diplomats said Egypt, Kuwait and
>   Qatar had also done so.
>
> ...
>
> The Gulf state is the fourth biggest contributor to UNRWA after the
>   United States, European Union and Britain, having contributed nearly
>   $100 million (£69 million) in 2015.
>
> Kuwait and United Arab Emirates – fellow members of the coalition –
>   also provide significant funding to UNRWA, donating nearly $50 million
>   (£34.5 million) between them last year.
>
> ...
>
> Diplomatic sources said the UN Relief and Works Agency for Palestine
>   Refugees in the Near East (UNRWA) would suffer if the blacklisting was
>   upheld, as Saudi allegedly threatened to pull its funding.

2. [Saudis exerted 'massive' pressure on U.N. to be removed from blacklist](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/06/09/middleeast/saudi-arabia-un-children/index.html)

Comment: So UN is a place that  wealthy  countries pay money to convict other countries !?

Comment: @user1, not only wealthy but also having veto powers, good diplomatic ties, and so on. Why is this surprise you?

Comment: How people all around the world Tolerate this?

Comment: @user1, how did you tolerate Mavi Marmara incident?

Comment: yes. we are weak and not organised, so cannot do anything. BTW it was not incident. it was a complete crime.